# c# - wmplib - playing 2 mp3 files but can get them in synic

Tags: c#, wmplib

I have 2 windowsMediaPlayer objects setup 
Both objects have the same mp3 song file but when I play them at the same time they are out of sync by a few seconds. The code I call to play them looks like this

```
     sound1.controls.play();
     sound2.controls.play();
```

Is it just because one play method is executed before the other and thus one fast then the other. Is their anyway I could sync them? I have tired messing with the rate of one track to match the other, but not getting it prefect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't get this perfect, the players cannot start at the same time by design.  You'll need to mix the two songs into a new song, the [NAudio library](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) can do this.

Comment: The thing is I was using the 2 obj like channels really. Where I could mute one channel at certain stages.

Comment: No problem, muting is multiplying the audio signal by zero.

Comment: I been reading though the source code of that link you sent me. Cant seem to find what I am looking for, any specific class? There are no comments in the source.

Comment: @Ciarán: the WaveMixerStream32 class ought to do the job.  "WaveStream that can mix together multiple 32 bit input streams."

Comment: Yea looked into that class, and tried to get it to work, but get loads of format exceptions, like IEEE floating point number. I will keep trying anyway. Thanks for your help!